# How To Use Resources Inside HTML Tag in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, resources

I know how to use resources by DataAnotation in class:

```
    [Display(Name="StreetDisplay", 
    ResourceType=typeof(Resources))]        
    public string Street { get; set; }
```

also in ActionLink:

```
     <li>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.StreetDisplay, "Index", "Home")</li>
```

What should I do if I want use resources within a h1 html tag?

`<h1>some multilangue text</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to output a resource string in the following way:

```
<h1>@Resources.StreetDisplay/h1>
```